# Priority Queue with heap sort not working correctly

Tags: c#, priority-queue, heapsort, binary-heap

I am attempting to write my own priority queue with a min heap sort but i am not getting the correct output.

My input data is 8 elements with different priorities:

```
[0] : 14
[1] : 5
[2] : 10
[3] : 9
[4] : 6
[5] : 3
[6] : 1
[7] : 2
```

The output should obviously show these priorities in order (lowest to highest) but it comes out like this:

```
[0] => Priority 1
[1] => Priority 14
[2] => Priority 5
[3] => Priority 10
[4] => Priority 9
[5] => Priority 6
[6] => Priority 3
[7] => Priority 2
```

The first element is correct at least, but after that its all incorrect.

This is how i add my data:

```
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item); // add to end of list

        SortUp(); // bubble the element up the heap
    }
    private void SortUp()
    {
        // the last element we just added
        int itemIndex = _data.Count - 1;
        while (true)
        {
            int parentIndex = (itemIndex - 1) / 2;

            //the lower the priority number, the higher the priority
            if (_data[itemIndex].Priority < _data[parentIndex].Priority)
            {
                //swap with parent
                T temp = _data[parentIndex];
                _data[parentIndex] = _data[itemIndex];
                _data[itemIndex] = temp;
                
                // update item index to parent index for next loop
                itemIndex = parentIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
         }
     }
```

Then i try to remove elements from the queue and this is where the order comes out incorrect based on the priorities:

```
    public T Pop()
    {
        item = _data[0];

        //get the last element and set it to front of queue
        int lastIndex = Count - 1;
        _data[0] = _data[lastIndex];
        _data.RemoveAt(lastIndex);

        SortDown();

        return item;
    }
    private void SortDown()
    {
        // item we are sorting is at front of the queue
        int itemIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int leftChildIndex = 2 * itemIndex + 1;
            int rightChildIndex = 2 * itemIndex + 2;

            // check if priority is higher than left child node
            if (leftChildIndex < Count && _data[itemIndex].Priority < _data[leftChildIndex].Priority)
            {
                int swapIndex;
                // check if priority is also higher than right child node
                if (rightChildIndex < Count && _data[itemIndex].Priority <_data[rightChildIndex].Priority) 
                {
                    swapIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    swapIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }

                //swap with child swapIndex
                T temp = _data[swapIndex];
                _data[swapIndex] = _data[itemIndex];
                _data[itemIndex] = temp;
                
                //update itemIndex to swapIndex for next loop
                itemIndex = swapIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Does any one know where my logic is off here i can't seem to see what i did wrong.

Comment: You should compare left child and right child and swap with item that has lower prioirty when you are Dequeing item. I think your code is just selecting right child without comparing with left child.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow, it checks the left child first and then it checks the right child, and selects left child if the right child does not have a lower priority.... unless i misunderstand you.

Comment: If both childs are valid for swapping, your code will always select the right child because right child will be checked after the left child. In this way, deque operation could flow into wrong way. For example, if you are re - arranging Que like [ *9 2 5 ] in lower priority, your code will select 5 for swapping with 9 instead of 2.

Comment: I got it working in the end :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
public T Deque()
{
    T retval = _data[0];
    _data[0] = _data[Count - 1];
    _data.RemoveAt(Count - 1);
    int cnt = 0;
    while(cnt < Count - 1)
    {
        int lcmp = 0, rcmp = 0;
        if(cnt * 2 + 1 < Count)
        {
            lcmp = _data[cnt].CompareTo(_data[cnt * 2 + 1]);
        }
        if(cnt * 2 + 2 < Count)
        {
            rcmp = _data[cnt].CompareTo(_data[cnt * 2 + 2]);
        }
        int target = -1;
        if(lcmp == -1 && rcmp == -1)
        {
            if(_data[cnt * 2 + 1].CompareTo(_data[cnt * 2 + 2]) != -1)
            {
                target = cnt * 2 + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                target = cnt * 2 + 2;
            }
        }
        else if(lcmp == -1)
        {
            target = cnt * 2 + 1;
        }
        else if(rcmp == -1)
        {
            target = cnt * 2 + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        T temp = _data[cnt];
        _data[cnt] = _data[target];
        _data[target] = temp;
        cnt = target;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Get both child's compare result, and if both side is valid for swapping, select item that has lower priority.

Comment: Hmm your code is a bit difficult to understand compared to my own..